# Rhino- Print to Console In Color

Tags: rhino

I am using **Rhino** JavaScript interpreter.

I am running a script which list in console some information. For easier readability, is there a way to print to console in color or bold?

Comment: What kind of console?

This is more likely to be a terminal question than anything else.

Comment: I am using a commercial application (dont have the source code for it) which is using Java. In order to manipulate data, I have the option to run Rhino Scripts. The console is part of this application...Just wondering if there is a way to use Java syntax to displayed colored text..Not sure if this answered your question or not :)

Comment: "The console is part of this application" -- meaning that the console itself is built into the commercial application? Then it would depend how the console itself works. How can you write to the console using Rhino right now? Or can you?

Comment: Yes, the console itself is built into the application. So, as you mentioned I think I am restricted on how the console itself works. Thanks for the advice